# OperationalError: invalid uri authority: anaconda3

Tags: python, anaconda, google-cloud-storage, conda, dask

When importing `gcsfs`

```
from gcsfs import GCSFileSystem
```

```html
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2d26262e0ad3> in <module>
----> 1 from gcsfs import GCSFileSystem

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gcsfs/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .core import GCSFileSystem
      2 from .mapping import GCSMap
      3 from ._version import get_versions
      4 
      5 __version__ = get_versions()["version"]

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gcsfs/core.py in <module>
      5 import textwrap
      6 
----> 7 import fsspec
      8 
      9 from base64 import b64encode, b64decode

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/__init__.py in <module>
      3 from .spec import AbstractFileSystem
      4 from .registry import get_filesystem_class, registry, filesystem
----> 5 from .mapping import FSMap, get_mapper
      6 from .core import open_files, get_fs_token_paths, open, open_local
      7 from . import caching

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/mapping.py in <module>
      1 from collections.abc import MutableMapping
      2 from .registry import get_filesystem_class
----> 3 from .core import split_protocol
      4 
      5 

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/core.py in <module>
      4 import os
      5 import logging
----> 6 from .compression import compr
      7 from .utils import (
      8     infer_compression,

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fsspec/compression.py in <module>
    120 
    121 try:
--> 122     import snappy
    123 
    124     snappy.compress

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snappy/__init__.py in <module>
      5 #logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
      6 import sys
----> 7 from .SnapPy import (AbelianGroup, HolonomyGroup, FundamentalGroup,
      8                      DirichletDomain, CuspNeighborhood, SymmetryGroup,
      9                      AlternatingKnotExteriors, NonalternatingKnotExteriors,

cython/core/basic.pyx in init SnapPy()

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spherogram/__init__.py in <module>
      1 from .graphs import *
      2 from .presentations import *
----> 3 from .links import *
      4 from .codecs import *
      5 #try:

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spherogram/links/__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .links import Crossing, Strand, Link, ClosedBraid
      2 
      3 from .tangles import Tangle, RationalTangle, ZeroTangle, InfinityTangle, IdentityBraid, join_strands
      4 from . import orthogonal
      5 Link.view = orthogonal.orthogonal_draw

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spherogram/links/links.py in <module>
----> 1 from .links_base import Crossing, Strand, CrossingStrand, CrossingEntryPoint
      2 from .invariants import Link, ClosedBraid

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spherogram/links/links_base.py in <module>
     30 # Looking up links in SnapPy's databases
     31 import snappy_manifolds
---> 32 DT_tables = snappy_manifolds.get_DT_tables()
     33 
     34 def lookup_DT_code_by_name(name):

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snappy_manifolds/database.py in get_DT_tables()
    761     RolfsenDTcodes = DTCodeTable(name = 'RolfsenDTcodes',
    762                                    table = 'link_exteriors',
--> 763                                    db_path = database_path)
    764     HTLinkDTcodes = DTCodeTable(name = 'HTLinkDTcodes',
    765                                   table = 'HT_links',

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snappy_manifolds/database.py in __init__(self, name, table, db_path, **filter_args)
    745             self.name = name
    746 
--> 747             self._connection = connect_to_db(db_path)
    748             self._cursor = self._connection.cursor()
    749 

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snappy_manifolds/database.py in connect_to_db(db_path)
    722     if sys.version_info >= (3,4):
    723         uri = 'file:' + db_path + '?mode=ro'
--> 724         return sqlite3.connect(uri, uri=True)
    725     elif sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    726         try:

OperationalError: invalid uri authority: anaconda3
```

Comment: What version of gcsfs are you using ?  And What version of anaconda3 did you download ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a package named `snappy` that isn't the compression library.  This is an unfortunate name collision on PyPI.

It looks like it's hard to import this other snappy library on your system.  Maybe uninstalling it would help?